# Duplicate method application:openURL

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, firebase, react-native

In my iOS project `AppDelegate.m` an error say that :

> Duplicate declaration of method 'application:openURL:options:'

This error appear when the Firebase Dynamic Link and Facebook SDK set up together, how can I combine both of this function?

**Facebook**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

**Firebase**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {
  return [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

**Answer (hope help someone)**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];

  if (!handled) {
    handled = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
  }

  return handled;
}
```